# NodeJS repeat and pause functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, time, callback, repeater

I have a function that repeats in NodeJS every minute with the help of the Repeat-package like this:

```
Repeat(checkCOS).every(10000, 'ms').start.in(5, 'sec');
```

My problem is that I want the repeater to wait until the callback-function has finished before it starts again. Is this possible to do or do you know any packages that I can use instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your `checkOS` is synchronous, then it's guaranteed to be completed before the next timer starts. No need to do anything about this.

If it's async and expects a `done` callback, you can do it like this with in-built `setTimeout`:

```
function timer() {
    checkOS(() => setTimeout(timer, 1000));
}
```